# How to monitor resources during slurm job?

Tags: memory, cpu, slurm, resource-monitor

I'm running jobs on our university cluster (regular user, no admin rights), which uses the SLURM scheduling system and I'm interested in plotting the CPU and memory usage over time, i.e while the job is running. I know about `sacct` and  `sstat` and I was thinking to include these commands in my submission script, e.g. something in the line of

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH <options>

# Running the actual job in background
srun my_program input.in output.out &

# While loop that records resources
JobStatus="$(sacct -j $SLURM_JOB_ID | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $6}')"
FIRST=0
#sleep time in seconds
STIME=15
while [ "$JobStatus" != "COMPLETED" ]; do
    #update job status
    JobStatus="$(sacct -j $SLURM_JOB_ID | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $6}')"
    if [ "$JobStatus" == "RUNNING" ]; then
        if [ $FIRST -eq 0 ]; then
            sstat --format=AveCPU,AveRSS,MaxRSS -P -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID} >> usage.txt
            FIRST=1
        else
            sstat --format=AveCPU,AveRSS,MaxRSS -P --noheader -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID} >> usage.txt
        fi
        sleep $STIME
    elif [ "$JobStatus" == "PENDING" ]; then
        sleep $STIME
    else
        sacct -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID} --format=AllocCPUS,ReqMem,MaxRSS,AveRSS,AveDiskRead,AveDiskWrite,ReqCPUS,AllocCPUs,NTasks,Elapsed,State >> usage.txt
        JobStatus="COMPLETED"
        break
    fi
done
```

However, I'm not really convinced of this solution:

- `sstat` unfortunately doesn't show how many cpus are used at the
  moment (only average)
- MaxRSS is also not helpful if I try to record memory usage over time
- there still seems to be some error (script doesn't stop after job finishes)

Does anyone have an idea how to do that properly? Maybe even with `top` or `htop` instead of `sstat`? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looking for an answer to this same question. I am already certain that neither `top` nor `htop` can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slurm offers a plugin to record a profile of a job (PCU usage, memory usage, even disk/net IO for some technologies) into a HDF5 file. The file contains a time series for each measure tracked, and you can choose the time resolution.

You can activate it with

```
#SBATCH --profile=<all|none|[energy[,|task[,|filesystem[,|network]]]]>
```

See the documentation [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/hdf5_profile_user_guide.html).

To check that this plugin is installed, run

```
scontrol show config | grep AcctGatherProfileType
```

It should output `AcctGatherProfileType   = acct_gather_profile/hdf5`.

The files are created in the folder referred to in the `ProfileHDF5Dir` Slurm configuration parameter (in `slurm.conf`)

As for your script, you could try replacing `sstat` with an SSH connection to the compute nodes to run `ps`. Assuming `pdsh` or `clush` is installed, you could run something like:

```
pdsh -j $SLURM_JOB_ID ps -u $USER -o pid,state,cputime,%cpu,rssize,command --columns 100 >> usage.txt
```

This will give you CPU and memory usage per process.

As a final note, your job never terminates simply because it will terminate when the `while` loop terminates, and the `while` loop will terminate when the job terminates... The condition `"$JobStatus" == "COMPLETED"`  will never be observed from within the script. When the job is completed, the script is killed.

Comment: I guess I can find it in the linked documentation but it would be nice if this gave a complete answer. Where can I find the HDF5 file that should be produced when a task using this #SBATCH command is run?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I can't find any `slurm.conf` where would this usually be stored? Edit: Sorry found one in `/etc/slurm`, but there is no entry for ProfileHDF5Dir. Is any default value used in that case?