# How can I know the real-time memory usage of a running job on slurm?

Tags: slurm

I know little about how cpu communicates with memories, so I’m not sure whether this is a ‘correct’ question to ask.

In a job script I submit to a slurm cluster, the script needs to read data from a database stored in the working dictionary. I want to monitor the memory used by running this script.

How can I write a bash script to do this? I have tried [@CoffeeNerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853964/how-to-monitor-resources-during-slurm-job)'s script. However, while the job is running, there is only one line of output in the file

```
AveCPU|AveRSS|MaxRSS
```

How can I modify this script to output the real-time memory usage?

I know `sstat` command, but I'm not sure whether something like `sstat -j $JOBID.batch --format=MaxVMSize` is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slurm has a plugin that records a 'profile' of a job (PCU usage, memory usage, etc) into a [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) file. It holds a time series for each item measured.

Use

```
#SBATCH --profile=<all|none|[energy[,|task[,|filesystem[,|network]]]]>
```

to activate it.

See the documentation [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/hdf5_profile_user_guide.html).

Comment: Where do I find this HDF5 file?

Comment: This is decided by the `ProfileHDF5Dir` configuration parameter

Comment: Right, so I assume a default is set in the above command since it is not specified?

Comment: It is defined in the `slurm.conf` file

Comment: Back here years later. Is there a way to define the directory in the batch file along with the command you give here? There is no ProfileHDF5Dir in the slurm.conf file and moreover it is a general file used by all users and so not writable. (Finally it would be inappropriate to use the same directory for all users.)